# What's wrong with this file Scanner code?

Tags: java

I am trying to search the File for characters in Java language. For that I am using `Scanner` to scan the file.

Well to check the Heirarchy work, I am using `System.out.print("Worked till here!");` so that I can check whether it is executed or not. I was able to execute the code till the last stage, but then I found that the essential `boolean` variable wasn't altered, which was under the condition to check whether there is a character match or not.

The file contents are as

> Ok, here is some text!
>
> Actually this file is created to test the validity of the java application
>
> Java is my favourite programming language.
>
> And I think I can score even more :)
>
> Wish me luck!

However, no matter what I search it always prompts me to be `false`.

Here is the code I am using

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Only write the output here!!!
    System.out.print("Write the character to be found in the File: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String character = sc.next();
    // Find the character
    System.out.println("Searching now...");
    getCharacterLocation(character);
    // Close the resource!
    sc.close();
    
}
```

The method call executed and the method is as

```
public static void getCharacterLocation (String character) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("File found...");
    File file = new File("res/File.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    int lineNumber = 0;
    int totalLines = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    // First get the total number of lines
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        totalLines++;
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Line looping! For Total Lines variable.");
    }
    int[] lineNumbers = new int[totalLines];
    int lineIndex = 0;
    System.out.println("Searching in each line...");
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        // Until the end
        /* Get each of the character, I mean string from
         * each of the line... */
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            // Until the end of line
            String characterInLine = sc.next();
            if(sc.findInLine(character) != null) {
                found = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(sc.nextLine() + "\n");
        lineNumber++;
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("Searching complete, showing results...");
    // All done! Now post that.
    if(found) {
        // Something found! :D
        System.out.print("Something was found!");
    } else {
        // Nope didn't found a fuck!
        System.out.println("Sorry, '" + character + 
                    "' didn't match any character in file.");
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Never mind the extra usage of variables, and arrays. I would use it in further coding if I can get the character and set the value to true.

Here is the output of this program.

#### Initial Stage

This is the initial stage for that. I wrote `Ok` in the input field, you can see `Ok` is the very first character in the File too.

[image]

#### Final Stage

This is the result after the execution.

[image]

Any help in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You count lines and don't restart the scanner.

```
boolean found = false;
// First get the total number of lines
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    totalLines++;
    sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Line looping! For Total Lines variable.");
}
int[] lineNumbers = new int[totalLines];
int lineIndex = 0;
System.out.println("Searching in each line..."); // <------
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
```

add e.g.

UPDATED from the comment

```
sc.close();
sc = new Scanner(file);
```

before the next `while(sc.hasNextLine())`

Comment: That, I never knew! :) Thanks alot, This is what I added to fix it, `sc.close(); sc = new Scanner(file);` you can include this in your answer too :) Thanks alot anyways ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a way to string your characters together and check them against your input. It appears that you don't currently have a way to do this in your code.

Try building an array of characters with your scanner, and moving through and doing a check of your input vs the indexes. Or maybe there is a way to implement the tonkenizer class achieve this.

Put remember, what you are looking for is not a character, it is a string, and you need to keep this in mind when writing your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you count your lines you use `while(sc.hasNextLine())`.
After this loop, your scanner is behind the last line, so when you go to your next loop `while(sc.hasNextLine()) {` it is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. You Iterated through your scanner here:

> ```
>  while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
>         totalLines++;
>         sc.nextLine();
>         System.out.println("Line looping! For Total Lines variable.");
>     }
> ```

So after this you have to reset it again to read for further processing.

1. While searching for character you are having two loops:

   ```
   while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
   // Until the end
   /* Get each of the character, I mean string from
    * each of the line... */
   while(sc.hasNext()) {
       // Until the end of line
       String characterInLine = sc.next();
       if(sc.findInLine(character) != null) {
           found = true;
       }
   }
   ```

   Here you just need a single loop like:

> ```
>   while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
>       String characterInLine = sc.nextLine();
>       if(characterInLine.indexOf(character) != -1) {
>         found = true;
>         break;
>       }
>    }
> ```